# how to properly use bootstrap datepicker with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

In my `application.js` I've added:

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

then I've added this helper in my `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
def datepicker (form, field)
    form.text_field(field, data: {provide: "datepicker",
                                  'date-format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                                  'date-autoclose': 'true',
                                  'date-today-btn': 'linked',
                                  'date-today-highlight': 'true'}).html_safe
  end
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_with(model: test, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if test.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(myform.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this test from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% test.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :test_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :test_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :test_desc %>
    <%= form.text_field :test_desc %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :test_expan %>
    <%= form.text_field :test_expan %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :test_date %>
    <%= datepicker(form, :test_date) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :ci %>
    <%= form.text_field :ci %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :test_complete %>
    <%= form.check_box :test_complete %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :tester %>
    <%= form.text_field :tester %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :test_other_cons %>
    <%= form.text_field :test_other_cons %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have a huge form, which contains a lot of textfields and checkboxes, but the datepicker shows at the end of the form, not right beneath of the textfield. I mean, I would like the calendar to show right beneath the textfield, not after the submit button.

How should I proceed to solve this? Am I missing something here?

Also, I'm using Linux Mint 18.3, Ruby on Rails 5.2.1, and I've tested it on Chromiun 69.0.3497.81 and Firefox 62.0, both of them the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a CSS issue rather than Rails.
You should ensure that you have included all the required CSS files for `bootstrap` and for `bootstrap-datepicker` and that should solve it. Check the `stylesheets/application.css` file in your project for the currently included css files.

Comment: I added `*= require bootstrap-datepicker` in my `application.css` file. Do I need to add something else?

Comment: Is it ok to assume you have the 'core' bootstrap css as well and haven't done anything weird in your custom css? You can perhaps try to get rid of everything except the date picker on your page to narrow down the issue...

Comment: you are safe to assume that

Comment: What happens when you use bootstrap's layout grid and when you remove the clutter (essentially everything except datepicker and form)?

Comment: the only thing I'm using in that view coming from bootstrap is the datepicker

Comment: What I mean is - can you try to use bootstrap's layout structure with classes .row .col to layout your form elements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181244/discussion-between-assembler-and-draganstankovic).